# Fade out button when not touching for 3 seconds and fade in when user touches the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, button, fadein

Problem:

I have a UIButton that I'd like to fade out for a few seconds when the user doesn't touch the screen and fade them in when the user touches the screen. I think I might need to use a timer and some animation in the viewdidload part

```
@IBOutlet var startStopButton:  UIButton!

@IBAction func startStopButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you here. Let me preface this answer with a usability concern. I'm not sure it makes sense to tap anywhere on the screen to reset (fade in) the button after X seconds (will the user know to do that?). You might want to add a button or some kind of text indicator to "tap here to reset the button(s)". This all ultimately depends on your application, but just throwing that out there :)

On with the answer!

The general idea here is you want to have a timer that runs a method every 1 second. If the timer hits zero, then you fade out and disable the startStop button. If the user taps anywhere on the screen (via gesture recognizer on the whole view), then fade the button in and enable it.

Now for the code part!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
// Create these 3 properties in the top of your class
var secondToFadeOut = 5 // How many second do you want the view to idle before the button fades. You can change this to whatever you'd like.
var timer = Timer() // Create the timer!
var isTimerRunning: Bool = false // Need this to prevent multiple timers from running at the same time.


@IBOutlet weak var startStopButton: UIButton! // The outlet for your button. This is used to fade it in and out, and enable / disable it.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startStopButton.isEnabled = true
    runTimer()

    // Add a tap gesture recognizer to the main view to determine when the screen was tapped (for the purpose of resetting the timer).
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

}

func runTimer() {
    // Create the timer to run a method (in this case... updateTimer) every 1 second.
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Set the isTimerRunning bool to true
    isTimerRunning = true
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    // Every 1 second that this method runs, 1 second will be chopped off the secondToFadeOut property. If that hits 0 (< 1), then run the fadeOutButton and invalidate the timer so it stops running.
    secondToFadeOut -= 1
    print(secondToFadeOut)
    if secondToFadeOut < 1 {
        fadeOutButton()
        timer.invalidate()
        isTimerRunning = false
    }
}

@objc func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // When the view is tapped (based on the gesture recognizer), reset the secondToFadeOut property, fade in (and enable) the button.
    //secondToFadeOut = 5
    fadeInButton()
    timer.invalidate()
    //if isTimerRunning == false {
    //    runTimer()
    //}
}

func fadeOutButton() {
    // Fade out your button! I also disabled it here. But you can do whatever your little heart desires.
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.startStopButton.alpha = 0.25
    }
    self.startStopButton.isEnabled = false
}
func fadeInButton() {
    // Fade the button back in, and set it back to active (so it's tappable)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.startStopButton.alpha = 1
    }
    self.startStopButton.isEnabled = true
}


@IBAction func startStopButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Start Stop Button Pressed")
}
}
```

Hope that makes sense, but do let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. It works well but when the startStopButton fades back in I can't seem to disable the timer because it goes on the timer again back to 0 and then fades out automatically. How do I disable this?

Comment: You're welcome for the help! You are correct, in the timer continues to fire until the button fades out. When the button fades back in, it's automatically on another 5 second timer until the screen is tapped. I thought this was the behavior you wanted. What would you like to have happen?

Comment: Thanks, I'd just like the timer to stop and go back to normal so there isn't a 5 second timer on when the startStopButton reappears. At the moment it automatically disappears, I'd like it to not to disappear when it fades in.

Comment: I edited my answer. All you need to on the tap method (tap gesture recognizer) is kill the timer.

Comment: Thanks again but it's still not working when I do this and now the tap gesture recogniser doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What isn't still working? I tested the above code locally and here is what it does: On app load, you see an *enabled* "Start Stop Button." - Automatically, a 5 second timer starts to fade the button out and disable it. Once the button fades out and disables, I can tap anywhere on the screen to fade the button back in, enable it, and kill the timer (per your request of "I'd just like the timer to stop and go back to normal so there isn't a 5 second timer on when the startStopButton reappears."). The button will not fade out anymore, and the Start Stop button is enabled

Comment: I should of been more specific: On app load, you see an enabled "Start Stop Button." - Tap anywhere on the screen and a 5 second timer starts to fade the button out and disable it. Once the button fades out and disables, I can tap anywhere on the screen to fade the button back in, enable it, and kill the timer so the button shows as it was before I first tapped it.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing from you as still finding it tricky to sort out, thanks.